# Vercel "This Serverless Function has crashed" with simple GraphQL request from SvelteKit app

Tags: graphql, svelte, vercel, aws-serverless

I am getting frequent, seemingly random errors on initial page load. I think the problem has to do with Vercel Serverless Functions.

I regularly get this error on  the website itself:
[image]

Full log from Vercel:

```
[GET] /
14:54:19:39
2022-07-21T12:54:19.426Z    3a175b6b-396b-45d5-b1a1-46072201cd6a    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"FetchError: request to 
https://api-eu-central-1.graphcms.com/v2/cl2k6hi1809a401xk4hd3h5zj/master failed, reason: 
Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was 
established","reason":{"errorType":"FetchError","errorMessage":"request to https://api-
eu-central-1.graphcms.com/v2/cl2k6hi1809a401xk4hd3h5zj/master failed, reason: Client 
network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was 
established","code":"ECONNRESET","message":"request to https://api-eu-central-
1.graphcms.com/v2/cl2k6hi1809a401xk4hd3h5zj/master failed, reason: Client network socket 
disconnected before secure TLS connection was 
established","type":"system","errno":"ECONNRESET","stack":["FetchError: request to 
https://api-eu-central-1.graphcms.com/v2/cl2k6hi1809a401xk4hd3h5zj/master failed, reason: 
Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established","    at 
ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:7892:18)","    at ClientRequest.emit 
(node:events:527:28)","    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)","    
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)","    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams
/destroy:157:8)","    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)","    at 
processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"]},"promise":
{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: FetchError: request to https://api-eu-
central-1.graphcms.com/v2/cl2k6hi1809a401xk4hd3h5zj/master failed, reason: Client network 
socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established","    at process.
<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:775:15)","    at process.emit 
(node:events:539:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:140:20)","    at 
processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:274:27)","    at 
processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)"]}[ERROR] 
[1658408059427] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response 
code: 400.RequestId: 2a0597b4-6684-4f2a-a724-2333b4f9332d Error: Runtime exited with 
error: exit status 128Runtime.ExitError
```

Example code from SvelteKit endpoint:

```js
import {client} from '$lib/js/graphql-client'
import {projectsQuery} from '$lib/js/graphql-queries'

export async function get() {
        let sm = 640;
        let md = 768;
        let lg = 1024;
        let xl = 1280;
        let xxl = 1536;
        
        const variables = {sm, md, lg, xl, xxl}

        const {projects} = await client.request(projectsQuery, variables) 

        return {
            body: {
                projects, sm, md, lg, xl, xxl
            }
        }
}
```

Now, other people seem to have similar problems:

- [Vercel + NextJS : Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established - Help - Fauna Forums](https://forums.fauna.com/t/vercel-nextjs-client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established/2722/3)
- [node.js - Getting a 504/502 error on api requests in Nextjs deployed on Vercel - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456980/getting-a-504-502-error-on-api-requests-in-nextjs-deployed-on-vercel)
- [[AWS-Lambda] - NetworkingError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established · Issue #3591 · aws/aws-sdk-js · GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3591)

Especially the last link makes it seem like the source of the problem lies in AWS Lambda. I do not expect a magic bullet, but I do want to make sure the problem is in fact what I think it is (and not a mistake in my code).

Has anyone found any workarounds? Ways of minimizing the probability of these functions crashing?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `index.js` in `vercel.json`. See [this link](https://shadowsmith.com/how-to-deploy-an-express-api-to-vercel) for more information.