NextJs MongoDB collection rewrite
so I was trying to fetch YouTube data v3 API, and due to the quota limit for API calls I decided to build a function that stores the API data in a MongoDB collection or updates it every time the call is successful, if the call fails it falls back to the database content. and it seems to be working fine in the localhost but in the Vercel link the POST request I made returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error and doesn't update or rewrite the content, take a look
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    // Parse incoming data (the new podcasts to replace the old content)
    const newPodcasts = await request.json();

    // Validate the incoming data (ensure it's an array)
    if (!Array.isArray(newPodcasts)) {
      return new NextResponse("Invalid data format. Expected an array.", {
        status: 400,
      });
    }

    // Connect to the database
    await connectDb();

    console.log("Clearing existing podcasts...");

    // Clear the existing podcast collection
    await Podcast.deleteMany({});

    console.log("Inserting new podcasts...");

    // Insert the new podcasts into the database
    const insertedPodcasts = await Podcast.insertMany(newPodcasts, {
      ordered: true,
    });

    console.log("Podcasts successfully replaced!");

    // Return a response indicating success
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Database successfully rewritten with new podcasts!",
        podcasts: insertedPodcasts,
        count: insertedPodcasts.length,
      },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      console.error(
        "Error replacing podcast collection:",
        err.message,
        err.stack
      );
    } else {
      console.error(
        "An unknown error occurred while replacing the podcasts:",
        err
      );
    }
    return new NextResponse("Failed to rewrite podcast collection", {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}


and here is the front-end function:
async function fetchYoutubePlaylist() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/fetch-youtube");

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch data from YouTube API");
      }

      const videos = await res.json();
      setVideosToDisplay(videos);
      if (videos.length > 0) {
        await fetch("/api/podcast", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(videos),
        });
      }

      console.log("YOUTUBE API FETCHED SUCCESSFULLY");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("TINY LOGS: FAILED TO FETCH DATA FROM YOUTUBE API", err);

      // FALLBACK TO DATABASE
      try {
        const dbRes = await fetch("/api/podcast");
        if (!dbRes.ok) {
          throw new Error("FAILED TO FETCH DATA FROM DATABASE");
        }

        const dbData = await dbRes.json();
        setVideosToDisplay(dbData);
      } catch (dbErr) {
        console.error(
          "TINY LOGS ERROR: FAILED TO FETCH DATA FROM DATABASE: ",
          dbErr
        );
      }
    }
  }

Thank you in advance, I'm stuck here.

have you looked at the function logs

Yes, all the functions normally work locally and on Vercel, except for this one it returns "504 Gateway timeout"

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456980/getting-a-504-502-error-on-api-requests-in-nextjs-deployed-on-vercel
